# Relationship between number connectives and number of propositions

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have to prove that the number of logical connectives is exactly one less than the number of propositions in a logical statement.

So basically I'm seeking help on how to start.

I was thinking of choosing $p, q, r$ some propositions.
So how to select the connectives generally.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: [Related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3602488/a-proposition-with-n-connectives-has-at-most-2n-1-subformulas)

Comment: And also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1025732/structural-induction-propostitonal-formulae-problem)

Answer (score 1):

*Long comment*

This kind of proof needs induction on the length of the formula, using the syntactical specifications of the language.

I assume that a formula is:

either (i) an *atom* or propositional letter: $p_i$, or

(ii) $(\lnot \varphi)$, or

(iii) $(\varphi \lor \psi)$, and similar for every other binary connective.

Thus, the base case is a single-atom formula (i): one propositional letter and zero connectives. It's fine.

Case (ii): let $\sigma := (\lnot \varphi)$ and assume that $\text {NumCon}(\varphi)= \text {NumProp}(\varphi)-1$.

What happens with $(\lnot \varphi)$ ?

We add a new connective and no propositional letters. Thus: $\text {NumCon}(\sigma)= (\text {NumProp}(\varphi)-1)+1=\text {NumProp}(\varphi)=\text {NumProp}(\sigma)$

*Thus, something went wrong*...

Maybe you have to check the statement of the problem.

Comment: I understood your answer ! Let me check again the problem. Thank you